# Pretty Link Lite Plugin on WP Multisite

Tags: multisite

I have a subdirectory install of the WP multiste and I'm trying to use the Pretty Link Lite Plugin to create shortlinks.

I'm also using the MU domain mapping plugin to map each subdirectory site to a domain name.

The pretty link manager creates shortlinks such as:

```
domain.com/shortlink       //base domain
domain.com/sub/shortlink2  //subdirectory domain
```

Is there any way to create a shortlink for:

```
mappedDomain.com/shortlink
```

as you would expect this plugin to accomplish?

Comment: I have checked with my multisite and pretty link lite is using the mapped domain name. Could it be that your domain mapping isn't installed correctly?

Comment: Are you using subdirectories?

Comment: yes, my subblogs are in subdirectories, some of them have their own domain and then pretty link lite is using the domain name. Does your domain mapping work as it should with your blogs?

Comment: just another thought ... look in your domain mapping options. Did you activate "Redirect administration pages to site's original domain (remote login disabled if redirect disabled)"? If so uncheck this and use the mapped domain name for the admin section (I have checked point 2+3 which is Permanent redirect and User domain mapping page and the other options are unchecked.

Comment: I'll give that a try. Does that mean I have to login to each admin individually?

Comment: That seemed to work mirage. You should make that an answer.

Comment: Glad it worked for you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

look in your domain mapping options. Did you activate "Redirect administration pages to site's original domain (remote login disabled if redirect disabled)"? If so uncheck this and use the mapped domain name for the admin section (I have checked point 2+3 which is Permanent redirect and User domain mapping page and the other options are unchecked.